# I have two queries against the same table with different groupings that I am joining

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have two queries against the same table with different groupings that I have joined together. The code works but it seems slow. I am sure, due to the similar nature of the queries, this code could be optimized.

```
SELECT A.BatchID,
       A.Lot_ID,
       A.SN,
       A.StepNum,
       A.StepName,
       A.ProcedureName,
       A.HMI_user,
       A.RecipeName,
       A.batchIdSN,
       A.t_stamp,
       A.Batch_Time AS 'Batch Time',
       B.BatchTimeTotal,
       B.t_stamp_start
FROM (SELECT g1.BatchID,
             g1.Lot_ID,
             g1.SN,
             g1.StepNum,
             g1.StepName,
             g1.ProcedureName,
             g1.HMI_user,
             g1.RecipeName,
             CONCAT(g1.BatchID,g1.SN) AS 'batchIdSN',
             CONVERT_TZ(g1.t_stamp, 'UTC', $timeZone$) AS 't_stamp',
             SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(g2.t_stamp,g1.t_stamp))/60) AS 'Batch_Time'
      FROM `SN_all_Batch_Data` g1
      Left JOIN `SN_all_Batch_Data` g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1 and g2.SN = g1.SN
      WHERE g1.BatchID > 0
      GROUP BY g1.BatchID, g1.StepNum) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT q.BatchID,
                  q.BatchTimeTotal,
                  MIN(q.t_stamp) AS 't_stamp_start'
           FROM(SELECT g1.BatchID,
                       CONVERT_TZ(g1.t_stamp, 'UTC', $timeZone$) AS 't_stamp',
                       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(g2.t_stamp,g1.t_stamp))/60) AS 'BatchTimeTotal'
                FROM `SN_all_Batch_Data` g1
                Left JOIN `SN_all_Batch_Data` g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1 and g2.SN = g1.SN
                WHERE g1.BatchID > 0
                GROUP BY g1.BatchID) q
           GROUP BY q.BatchID) B
ON A.BatchID = B.BatchID
```

Any optimization guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). In addition, as well as the above, questions about query optimisation always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Although it is hard to figure out what the query is doing, without any explanation/sample data etc; but looking at the join conditions (`id = id + 1`), are your `id` values really continuous ?

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  All those non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` must be in `SELECT` statement.  Your code won't even run in any other dbms.

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected result. I guess you are fetching some data based on ranking. We will try our best to provide you the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the query you provided works in your system. Maybe an intermediate table can save the repetitive work.
You may firstly create a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE temp1 AS
SELECT g1.BatchID,
       g1.Lot_ID,
       g1.SN,
       g1.StepNum,
       g1.StepName,
       g1.ProcedureName,
       g1.HMI_user,
       g1.RecipeName,
       CONCAT(g1.BatchID,g1.SN) AS 'batchIdSN',
       CONVERT_TZ(g1.t_stamp, 'UTC', $timeZone$) AS 't_stamp',
       SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(g2.t_stamp,g1.t_stamp))/60) AS 'BatchTimeTotal'
 FROM `SN_all_Batch_Data` g1
 Left JOIN `SN_all_Batch_Data` g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1 and g2.SN = g1.SN
 WHERE g1.BatchID > 0;
```

Then the following steps would be

```
SELECT A.*,
       B.BatchTimeTotal,
       B.t_stamp_start
FROM (SELECT g1.BatchID,
             g1.Lot_ID,
             g1.SN,
             g1.StepNum,
             g1.StepName,
             g1.ProcedureName,
             g1.HMI_user,
             g1.RecipeName,
             g1.batchIdSN,
             g1.t_stamp,
             g1.BatchTimeTotal AS 'Batch Time'
      FROM temp1 g1
      GROUP BY g1.BatchID, g1.StepNum) A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT q.BatchID,
                  q.BatchTimeTotal,
                  MIN(q.t_stamp) AS 't_stamp_start'
           FROM temp1 q
           GROUP BY q.BatchID) B
ON A.BatchID = B.BatchID
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and see if it speeds things up.

Comment: If you are using 8.0, see `WITH`.